# Delpoying farm solution (Application Page) sharepoint 2010 --Access denied

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise, application-pages

I am deploying an application page (globally), I have a button on the editform.aspx.  When a user clicks on the button, it redirects to the application page in a new window but I am getting an error Access denied.

Below is my code in the page load function:

```
           SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {if (Request.QueryString["IDs"] != null)
                {

                    ticketID= Request.QueryString["IDs"].ToString();

                }
                else
                {
                    ticketID= "";
                }
                    ticketIdTEXTBOX.Text = ticketID;
});
```

I am getting Access Denied, screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: If you comment out that section of code, do you still get the access denied message when viewing the page?

Comment: yes john i still get the access denied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using firebug (or chrome or ie dev tools) check if your redirect button redirects you to correct address. (For example you may expect that it redirects to `http://mysite/sites/cars/_layouts/myApplicationPage.aspx`, but it actually redirects to `http://mysite/_layouts/myApplicationPage.aspx` where you get access denied).

And also (this is not an answer, but note), it is absolutely no make sense to  use `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` to access `Request.QueryString`.

**edit**
_layouts is a virtual directory in iis, which means that it maps to the physical path (for sharepoint it is `14\template\layout`). Every sharepoint web application has this virtual directory,  which means that yes, it is accessible between all web applications.

You may have two  site collections under `http://mysite/` and `http://mysite/sites/sitecol`. Your application page is accessible using `http://mysite/_layouts/myapplicationpage.aspx` and `http://mysite/sites/sitecol/_layouts/myapplicationpage.aspx`. But when user access to this application pages security still working for user, because it requests page in particular site collection. And this means that if user has no sufficient rights under `http://mysite/` he gets access denied under `http://mysite/_layouts/myapplicationpage.aspx`, but can successfully navigate to `http://mysite/sites/sitecol/_layouts/myapplicationpage.aspx` (again, if user has rights).
Hope I answer your question.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i think that the url might be the issue ...'sitecollname' is the sitecollection i m using for development.... http://mysite/sites/sitecollname/sitename/Home.aspx ...the link that have given is http://mysite/_Layouts, i am assuming that the layout folder resides under the webapplication? any suggestions?

Comment: The Layouts folder is a virtual directory that exists beneath each and every Site Collection on each and every web application.

Comment: @spStacker, please refer to my update, James Love thanks for follow up

Comment: Excellent! it was the url i changed it from "http://mysite/_layouts/myapplicationpage.aspx,"  TO "http://mysite/sites/sitecol/_layouts/myapplicationpage.aspx" ..Thanks a lot guys!..Kai Thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: You are welcome. If you have subsites under site collection, you should redirect to relative to subsite address (for example `http://mysite/sites/sitecollname/sitename/_layouts/myapplicationpage.aspx`), because your particular user (again under permissions) may has no access to root site.

Comment: I did face the same issue and the reason was perfectly given  by @Kai  . What is the solution for it ? We have moved from http://mysite/ in another envronment to http://mysite/sites/sitecol in current envirnment . So is there a way i can get rid of the error ?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue in the past.  I was able to get through the problem by using teh Farm Account to deploy the solution.  Hopefully this helps you out!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all resources the page uses are accessible to the current user. Things to consider include but are not limited to:

- Master Page checked in and viewable by user
- CSS files stored in SharePoint are checked in and viewable by user
- JavaScript files stored in SharePoint are checked in and viewable by user
- Image files (including favicon) stored in SharePoint are checked in and viewable by user
- Web Parts and other controls on the page don't utilize resources not accessible by the user